# Use netem and set pfifo(_fast) on same interface

Tags: networking, network-traffic

I have a linux server where I want to configure the qdisc on an interface using netem with different parameters (loss, delay, rate) but also to set the queueing discipline to be pfifo_fast. Somehow the command `tc qdisc add dev <interface_name> root pfifo_fast netem rate <rate> delay <delay>` does not work. Is it even possible to have both some netem settings and pfifo_fast set on same interface?